# How to detect if .exe file contains uncompiled code

Tags: exe, reverse-engineering, decompiling

Recently I discovered that .exe files sometimes still hold their source code (readable code).

- I opened an exe in IDA and it told me it was written in .NET and I could see the source code opening the exe with a .NET decompiling program (DNspy).
- Soon after I made an exe from a python script using pyinstaller. And similarly but with another program I was able to retrieve the original code from only the exe.

But opening the exe with IDA did not give me any indication that it was written in python/ build with pyinstaller. So I wonder if there is a program/tool/method that could detect how an exe was generated (maybe by looking at some magic bytes or something) ? Generally I would like to know for an exe if I can retrieve the source code.

Comment: *could see the source* - do you mean *readable* code or the original code like the author wrote it? To decompile to readable code, well that *is* what a decompiler does. But I'd love to be proven wrong. Can you show a screenshot from the decompiled code with meaningfull variable names?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes I mean readable code, with their original meaningfull variable names!